# Изменение MAC адреса на Raspberry Pi Pico W через MicroPython

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

Хочу сделать несколько локальных серверов, у которых будут свои личные настройки в роутере, но для этого нужно менять MAC адреса. Как его изменить для подключения к сети через библиотеку network? Пробовал через `Wlan.config(mac=new_mac)`, но это запрещено при использования вне точки доступа. К примеру, нужно подключиться к сети BestWIFI с паролем 12345678 с MAC адресом 00:11:22:33:44:55, а потом с 11:22:33:44:55:66.